# Hibernate JDBCConnectionException: Communications link failure and java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Whenever the connection is idle it starts giving this error. When we refresh the page once or twice it starts working fine again.

How can we fix this?

```
DEBUG DefaultConnectionTester - Connection com.mysql.jdbc.Connection@1a087ae failed default system-table Connection test with an Exception!
java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: java.io.EOFException, underlying cause: null
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
java.io.EOFException
STACKTRACE:
java.io.EOFException
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1395)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1539)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1930)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1168)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1279)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQuery(MysqlIO.java:1225)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2278)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2225)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1163)
at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getTables(DatabaseMetaData.java:3372)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnectionNoQuery(DefaultConnectionTester.java:185)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(DefaultConnectionTester.java:62)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(AbstractConnectionTester.java:67)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.testPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:368)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.finerLoggingTestPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:318)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.refurbishIdleResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:308)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1999)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1714)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1930)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1168)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1279)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQuery(MysqlIO.java:1225)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2278)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2225)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1163)
at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getTables(DatabaseMetaData.java:3372)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnectionNoQuery(DefaultConnectionTester.java:185)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(DefaultConnectionTester.java:62)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(AbstractConnectionTester.java:67)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.testPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:368)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.finerLoggingTestPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:318)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.refurbishIdleResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:308)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1999)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
DEBUG BasicResourcePool - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@4aa512 [managed: 5, unused: 5, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@d6dc32)
DEBUG BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 5
DEBUG C3P0PooledConnectionPool - Testing PooledConnection    [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@4e6f7c] on IDLE CHECK.
DEBUG BasicResourcePool - trace   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@4aa512 [managed: 4, unused: 4,   excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@d6dc32)
DEBUG BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 6
DEBUG C3P0PooledConnectionPool - Testing PooledConnection  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@197b44c] on IDLE CHECK.
DEBUG GooGooStatementCache - checkinAll():    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 0; checked out: 0; num connections: 0; num keys: 0
DEBUG C3P0PooledConnectionPool - Test of PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5aa6b3] on IDLE CHECK has FAILED.
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is invalid
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.testPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:427)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.finerLoggingTestPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:318)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.refurbishIdleResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:308)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1999)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
DEBUG BasicResourcePool - BasicResourcePool: An idle resource is broken and will be purged. [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5aa6b3]
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is invalid
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.finerLoggingTestPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:324)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.refurbishIdleResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:308)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1999)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
DEBUG DefaultConnectionTester - Connection com.mysql.jdbc.Connection@13bcbbb failed default system-table Connection test with an Exception!
java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: java.io.EOFException, underlying cause: null
```

Comment: Post your configuration for JDBC, including the c3p0 parameters, especially the idle test query.

Comment: This seems to be debug logging, and might just indicate that the connection is longer idle in the connection pool than the idle timeout configured on your server. Does this actually affect your application? If so, you might be keeping connections open in your servlet, instead of closing them (thus releasing them to the connection pool) when your done.

Comment: Thanks. After fetching the required data, i am closing the connection. But the error remains the same. `
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">180</property>

Comment: Sorry I missed this. I am running this validation query but not idle test query. Are they the same or different?<property name="hibernate.validationQuery">select now()</property>